# I get permission denied when I try to compile and run my program in c. What could be the problem?

Tags: c, windows, compiler-errors, permission-denied

Message

```
Cannot open output file F:\programming\simpletrialexpression.exe: permission denied
[Error] Id returned 1 exist status
```

Comment: What OS are you using? Did you try running it as administrator? Why is it `c` tagged?

Comment: Where is your code ? What are the rights on the file ? You might not be the owner of the file or you might need to open it in read only.

Comment: When and where do you get this error? What are you trying to do when you get this error? And please read (or refresh) [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: You should copy&paste the error message instead of typing it by hand. The 2nd line seems to contain typos. Probably it is `[Error] ld returned 1 exit status`. You should always show the command together with the error message in your question.

Answer (score 2):

The output file already exists and ld is not allowed to write to it. Possibly because it is already running somewhere in the background.

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is that some anti virus software blocks access to `.exe` files, in order to prevent infection. Try to disable that software, or place the `ld.exe` on the whitelist.